# Multiple regular expressions in python to check string

Tags: python

I am trying to write a regular expression statement that checks a string meets the following:

begins with three zeros, is followed by up to four letters, is then followed by a dash, is followed by eight characters that are lower case letters or digits, another dash, then a suffix that is either ab cd or kys.

```
^[0]{3}[-](?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9]).{8,}[-]([ab][cd][kys])
```

I'm a little confused on how I should be breaking up the eight charaters portion and the suffex portion. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Can you post a couple of good and bad string examples?

Comment: Is that any unicode lower case or a-z?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need this:

```
^[0]{3}[a-zA-Z]{,4}\-[a-z0-9]{8}\-((ab)|(cd)|(kys))$
```